# How Linux find command works with exec

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I would like to understand how I get this command:

```
find <dir> -name '*.zip' -exec unzip "{}" \;
```

To get the extracted files put into a different location than the current.

Also, what do the "{}" and \; mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Which parts of the man page are you having trouble with?

Comment: You could have just answered that there is a thing called Man page (which I have just discovered thanks to you) and that I can change the -exec to -execdir.
Instead, you chose to downvote and sound condescending. This is a place to ask questions, and not everyone here know as much as you do, don't ever forget that.

Comment: Except that I didn't downvote, but thanks for being presumptive.

Comment: Me presuming you were the one to downvote wasn't the problem with how you answered... Thank you anyway.

Comment: @theexplorer, don't be too put off my Ignacio's response.  In terms of common usage in computer forums, he was not at all rude.  Indeed, his response was a fairly typical response to what is reasonably considered to be a rude question.  The question can be considered rude because it can easily be answered by referring to the basic documentation and asking it demonstrates a lack of respect for the reader's time.   Note that I do not consider the question rude, nor do I consider Ignacio's response rude.  Just verbose.  He probably should have just said "RTFM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used *-execdir* instead of *-exec*:

```
find <dir> -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip "{}" \;
```

This will use the original location of the extracted file as the destination directory.

{} will be replaced with each of the files to get processed.
; is the terminator for the options

Both {} and ; may be escaped to prevent them from being interpreted.